# Can I upload a deb package with an MIT License to PPA?

Tags: ppa, packaging

I'm trying to build a deb package from source with `bzr dh-make` and `bzr builddeb`, but [bzr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Bazaar) automatically adds the [GPL license](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_General_Public_License) to my source code folder. Is it allowed to upload projects licensed under the [MIT License](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIT_License) in a personal [PPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_Package_Archive)?

Comment: I think so. The only requirement is that your software must be "free", with "free" being defined [here](https://help.launchpad.net/Legal/ProjectLicensing).

Comment: IIRC, the files created by `dh-make` are only a template, which you can (and probably should) modify to suit your needs before building the actual source package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Launchpad PPA Terms of Use](https://help.launchpad.net/PPATermsofUse), OSI or FSF approved licences are allowed and the MIT licence has both approvals.

You can tell [`dh_make`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man8/dh_make.8.html) which licence to use:

```
dh_make -c mit
```

`dh_make` has a few licences inbuilt, for others you will have to manually edit the files later.